# java: incompatible types: T cannot be converted to java.lang.String

Tags: java, generics, encryption, stack, tink

I am currently working on a encryption and decryption service for my application, using Google Tink.

The problem is the following: I want to program it without using (nearly) duplicate code and  therefore I had the idea of using generics.

If parsing the Strings to a byte[] is the only option I will be doing that, but I'd rather not.

These are the methods & variables:

The 3 Stacks I am using:

```
private Stack<String> plaintextAccInformation = new Stack<>();
private Stack<byte[]> encryptedAccInformation = new Stack<>();
private Stack<String> decryptedAccInformation = new Stack<>();
```

The method, used to get the information from the Stack (which I wanted to solve with generics and also is not working). No. Parsing does not work, as the method has to be accessible with two different datatypes.

```
private <T> Account getInformation(Stack<T> stack) {
    boolean isApproved = stack.peek();
    stack.pop();
    boolean isAdmin = stack.peek();
    stack.pop();
    double balance = stack.peek();
    stack.pop();
    String password = stack.peek();
    stack.pop();
    String iBan = stack.peek();
    stack.pop();
    String uuid = stack.peek();
    stack.pop();

    return new Account(uuid, iBan, password, balance, isAdmin, isApproved);
}
```

The method used to encrypt all the data of an Account object.
The idea is to iterate through the ```Stack plaintextAccInformation``` and encrypt every variable in the Account object and then save each encrypted variable to a new ```Stack encryptedAccInformation```

```
public Account encrypt(Account account) throws GeneralSecurityException {
        this.plaintextAccInformation.empty();
        this.encryptedAccInformation.empty();

        agjEncryption = new AesGcmJce(key.getBytes());

        this.plaintextAccInformation.push(account.getUuid());
        this.plaintextAccInformation.push(account.getIban());
        this.plaintextAccInformation.push(account.getPassword());
        this.plaintextAccInformation.push(String.valueOf(account.getBalance()));
        this.plaintextAccInformation.push(String.valueOf(account.isAdmin()));
        this.plaintextAccInformation.push(String.valueOf(account.isApproved()));

        Iterator<String> iterator = plaintextAccInformation.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            encryptedAccInformation.push(agjEncryption.encrypt(plaintextAccInformation.peek().getBytes(), aad.getBytes()));
            plaintextAccInformation.pop();
        }

        return getInformation(this.encryptedAccInformation);
    }
```

The method used to decrypt the variables saved in the ```Stack  encryptedAccInformation``` and save it to the ```Stack decryptedAccInformation```

```
    public Account decrypt() throws GeneralSecurityException {
        this.decryptedAccInformation.empty();

        this.agjDecryption = new AesGcmJce(key.getBytes());

        Iterator<byte[]> iterator2 = encryptedAccInformation.iterator();
        while (iterator2.hasNext()) {
            decryptedAccInformation.push(new String(agjDecryption.decrypt(encryptedAccInformation.peek(), aad.getBytes())));
            encryptedAccInformation.pop();
        }

        return getInformation(this.decryptedAccInformation);
    }
```

Comment: I don't know why the code isn't showing up as code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're sure the stack will always be in the order you expect here (which you seem to be).

Instead of a generic stack (which I believe limits you to only one value of T), you could use a stack of `Object` and cast the results of the `peek()` function.

```
private Account getInformation(Stack<Object> stack) {
        Boolean isApproved = (Boolean) stack.peek();
        stack.pop();
        Boolean isAdmin = (Boolean) stack.peek();
        stack.pop();
        Double balance = (Double) stack.peek();
        stack.pop();
        String password = (String) stack.peek();
        stack.pop();
        String iBan = (String) stack.peek();
        stack.pop();
        String uuid = (String) stack.peek();
        stack.pop();

        return new Account(uuid, iBan, password, balance, isAdmin, isApproved);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Even though, I've noticed, that I would have to rewrite the whole class, your solution worked for me.